# using 2 different jquery releases on the same page

Tags: jquery, tabs, carousel, jcarousel

I am using this jquery plugin for a carousel controller http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/, it is based on jquery release 1.2.1

I also need to have tabs on the page, but when including the current jquery release in the page, the carousel stops working.

Is there a way to have them both live together on the same page, or is there a way to have tabs work under realease 1.2.1?

I rather not rebuild the carousel on another plugin, since this one is already skinned and works just as needed.

I tried using jQuery.noConflict, the jcarousel controller still didn't work.

Comment: Possibly Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117463/two-jquery-versions-on-the-same-page

Answer (score 1):

There are [tons](http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/05/7-powerful-image-carousels-for-web.html) of other carousel plugins that you could use ([this one](http://sroucheray.org/blog/demos/jquery-infinite-carousel/) looks pretty good). Is there any reason you need to use that specific one? If not, I'd recommend you save yourself a lot of headache and simply switch to a different plugin.

Otherwise, [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) *should* work. If not, then post the code you're using so we can tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say, you are going to want to take the time to a) fix the old plugin to work on newer versions of jQuery yourself, or b) switch to a carousel that works with the new versions of jQuery.  Including two versions of jQuery on a site is **bad practice**, and you will be *asking for trouble later*, but it is not impossible.

You may be able to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/oldcarousel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery12 = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
```

Assuming that `oldcarousel.js` uses the closure (meaning the first and last lines of code look like this):

```
(function($){
  // and that all plugin code in here references $ not jQuery
})(jQuery);
```

It should be able to "hang on" to jQuery 1.2 after 1.4 overwrites it.

It might also work to change the include order:
You may be able to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/oldcarousel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery12 = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

As passing `true` to [`.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict) should restore the `$` and `jQuery` aliases from the new version.

Answer (score 0):

This one over at jQuery API docs might help you: [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Have a nice day.

Comment: I did try using jQuery.noConflict, the jcarousel controller still didn't work.