# $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow'); is not working in my page

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have already included jquery.js and jquery.1.3.2.js on my page for other functionality.I think it is getting conflicted with other.plz reply

Comment: This is a poor question, please include some code samples and what other frameworks you're using (if any). Also either animate HTML or BODY, why would you want both?

Comment: Parimal Naik - Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a moment to read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq as it gives helpful information on posting questions. :o) You can edit your question or use these comments to provide more information. Then when someone has given a suitable answer, click the checkmark next to that answer. Thanks. :o)

Comment: @Marko - Please try to be more patient with new users. ;o)

Answer (score 2):

Why would you include 2 different versions of jQuery on the same page? jQuery is pretty good with backwards compatibility, so try using ONLY the latest.

Answer (score 0):

If jquery.js is in fact jquery 1.4.2, then you must read this for example:

[Two jQuery versions on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117463/two-jquery-versions-on-the-same-page)